# Can we use System Env Variables in Postman while creating Kafka Connector(s)

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, postman, connector

We have deployed Customized Confluent Kafka Connector as statefulset in Kubernetes, which mounts secrets from Azure KeyVault. These secrets contain db username and password & are meant to be used while creating connectors via rest endpoint `https://kafka.mydomain.com/connectors` using Postman.

The secrets are being loaded as environment variables in container. And `kubernetes-ingress-controller` - *path based routing* is used for exposing rest endpoint.

So far, our team is unable to use the environment variables while creating connector through Postman.

Connector config:

```
{
 "name": "TEST.CONNECTOR.SINK",
    "config": {
        
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "errors.log.include.messages": "true",
    "table.name.format": "AuditTransaction",
    "connection.password": "iampassword",             <------------ (1)
    "flush.size": "3",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "TEST.CONNECTOR.SOURCE-AuditTransaction",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "connection.user": "iamuser",                     <------------ (2)
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "name": "TEST.CONNECTOR.SINK",
    "errors.tolerance": "all",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:sqlserver://testdb.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=mytestdb01",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "insert.mode": "insert",
    "errors.log.enable": "true",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter"
}  
}
```

***(1) and (2)*** - Here we want to use system environment variables with Values - `$my_db_username=iamuser`, `$my_db_password=iampassword`. We have tried using `"$my_db_username"` and `"$my_db_password"` there but in logs of Connector Pod, it doesn't resolve to the respective values.

Logs:

```
[2020-07-28 12:31:22,838] INFO Starting JDBC Sink task (io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask:44)
[2020-07-28 12:31:22,839] INFO JdbcSinkConfig values: 
    auto.create = false
    auto.evolve = false
    batch.size = 3000
    connection.password = [hidden]
    connection.url = jdbc:sqlserver://testdb.database.windows.net:1433;databaseName=mytestdb01
    connection.user = $my_db_username
    db.timezone = UTC
    delete.enabled = false
    dialect.name = 
    fields.whitelist = []
    insert.mode = insert
    max.retries = 10
    pk.fields = []
    pk.mode = none
    quote.sql.identifiers = ALWAYS
    retry.backoff.ms = 3000
    table.name.format = AuditTransaction
```

Is there any way to use system/container environment variables in this config, while creating connectors with Postman or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally did it!! Using `FileConfigProvider`. All the needed information was [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/security.html#externalizing-secrets).

We just had to parametrize `connect-secrets.properties` according to our requirement and substitute env vars value on startup.

This doesn't allow using Env Vars via Postman. But parametrized `connect-secrets.properties` specifically tuned according to our need did the job and `FileConfigProvider` did the rest by picking values from `connect-secrets.properties`

### Update

Found a way to implement this using env vars [here](https://github.com/giogt/kafka-env-config-provider).